# alex gorbatchev's syntax highlighter not working for me

Tags: javascript, html, css, syntaxhighlighter

I'm just posting my entire page to prevent confusion. I've stared at each link and checked the folder for the files. it all seems to be there. what's not working? very frustrated, could use a  fresh pair of eyes. all my page displays is the content of the pre, but without any formatting. again, thanks for the help

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" dir="ltr"> 

<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 



<!--STYLESHEET LINKS-->

<link  href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link  href="shThemeDefault.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link  href="shCore.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<!--SYNTAX HIGHLIGHTER-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="shCore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="shBrushPhp.js"></script>

<!--JQUERY and PROCESSING SCRIPTS-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="processing.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="init.js"></script>




</head>

<body>
<pre class="brush: php">

$last_modified = filemtime("header.php");
echo("last modified: ");
echo(date("m.j.y h:ia", $last_modified));

</pre>

<script type="text/javascript">
SyntaxHighlighter.HighlightAll();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Four things:

1. SYNTAX HIGHLIGHTER - put the .js files AFTER the jquery, jQueryUI, etc. scripts.  The order is important!
2. use $(document).ready to make sure that all the js files are loaded before the body content tries to use it.
3. Are you using firebug or some such tool to check for script errors in the browser?
4. Are you getting any errors at all or just not seeing the highlighting effect?

Comment: What if I want to use SyntaxHighLighter without reloading document? I have a textarea, and I want preview of textarea under it using SyntaxHighLighter... Same like how we get preview of question or answer when we post on stackoveflow...

Answer (score 0):

By replacing:

```
SyntaxHighlighter.HighlightAll();
```

with

```
SyntaxHighlighter.all();
```

your sample code works for me.